# HP 5500 'display current-configuration' without 'super' permissions

Tags: switching, hp

I need to get configuration file from my hp 5500 switches. When I connect to it with ssh I need to enter a login and password and then `super` command to execute `display current-configuration`. I need to execute this command without the `super` command. I found `command-privilege` with it I can set privilege level of command `display current-configuration` to `0` and `super` command becomes unnecessary.

Is there any other way to do `display current-configuration` without `super` when using ssh?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

**When** you are using SSH to access the switch you are using a certain username and password. The fact that you need to elevate your privilege level by using the super command means that the account you are using doesn't have the highest privilege level.

So in order to prevent elevating your privilege level via the super command you should already have a sufficient privilege level to begin with.

In Comware 5, the OS running on the HP 5500 series switches, the privilege levels are defined as follows:

> *0-VISIT, 1-MONITOR, 2-SYSTEM, 3-MANAGE*

Privilege level 3, also know as manager level, is the highest privilege level.
In order to successfully login with privilege level 3, which is equal to super, you would need to specify that for the user account you are using.

Configuring a privilege level for a local user goes as follows:

> - < HP 5500 > system-view
> - [ HP 5500 ] local-user
> - [ HP 5500-luser-The_name_of_your_user_account ]  authorization-attribute level 3

This in term means that you would authenticate locally on the switch which is know as "**Local level switching authentication**". If you however are using a RADIUS server, HWTACACS server, you are authenticating remotely which is know as "**Remote level switching authentication**". In that scenario the remote authentication server should be configured to provide your user with level 3 privileges.

For further information regarding the Authentication Authorization Accounting, also know as AAA, implementation on the HP 5500 I would redirect you to the "HP 5500 EI & 5500 SI Switch Series Security Configuration Guide":

- [HP 5500 EI & 5500 SI Switch Series Security Configuration Guide](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c03962889-1%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)

For more information regarding the privilege level I would redirect you to:

- [H3C Privilege Level Switching Authentication Technology White Paper](http://www.h3c.com/portal/Products___Solutions/Technology/Security_and_VPN/Technology_White_Paper/200911/654661_57_0.htm)

Comment: I'm confused on your disclaimer. Not only are opinions  discouraged, but the mentality behind SE is authoritative Q&As; on top of that, you don't have any opinions in your post.  Consider removing the disclaimer?

Comment: The disclaimer may be required by his employer for anything he posts online.

Comment: @legioxi Stack Exchange [strongly encourages taglines or disclaimers in the users profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed/), instead of each response

Answer (score 0):

Change your user privileges:

```
local-user <username>
authorization-attribute level 3
```

This way, when you log in the switch, you'll be already logged in as "super".

[HP 5500 Configuration Guide](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/device_help/H3C-Manuals/5500/5500-Configuration-Guide(R2215).pdf)

EDIT: correcting privilege level as noted by Jason Cederboom